# How to interpret the values in auto arima plot and store it in a dataframe

Tags: r, forecasting

I want to use forecasting to my data and I have used the auto arima method and got graph.

The following is my code,

```
fit <- auto.arima(a)
LH.pred <- forecast(fit,h=30)
plot(LH.pred)
```

I want to interpret the graphs as values and store it in a data frame, so that I can make calculations based on the forecasting.

Can anybody let me know how to take the values from the graph and store it in a data frame?

Also when I used the auto arima method, the days just got converted to days count from 1-1-1970. I want to convert back to normal dates. Can anybody plese help in that too?

Thanks
Observer

Comment: See `attributes(LH.pred)`. You should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: @David Arenburg But in that there is no variable that shows the future values right?

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(LH.pred)`

Comment: @RobHyndman I am little confused about using that. There is a forecast column along with LO, HO , 80,95. Is there any link in which I can view the explanation of how to interpret it?

Also, I want to  know, if we can make the prediction until a particular value is reached? Instead of giving a common h=30 , Is it possible to predict until my sum reaches a particular value?

Comment: Read the help file `?forecast`. And if you have a new question, ask it properly, not in the comments.

Comment: @RobHyndman Sorry for asking in comments. New to Stack Over flow. Didn't know about it. I am having a look at the forecast help page, but not sure whether we can predict until a particular value is reached. So only thought of clarifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the values from the graph is not really necessary. The graph consists of two parts. The first one is the time series 'a' used to build 'fit'. It is still stored in 'fit' as 'fit$x'. The second part is the forecast. You can take it from 'LH.pred' using 'as.data.frame(LH.pred)'.

Comment: I am little confused about using that. There is a forecast column along with LO, HO , 80,95. Is there any link in which I can view the explanation of how to interpret it? Also, I want to know, if we can make the prediction until a particular value is reached? Instead of giving a common h=30 , Is it possible to predict until my sum reaches a particular value?